# IAT patch advanced example

Tags: security, dll, portable-executable, dll-injection

I need to patch a windows application using IAT patch, the main interest is to create a kind of malicious behavior.
The malicious behavior can be hiding some files/processes or stealing passwords from the app and others.

I have the code which injects a DLL into an external process and also have the DLL which its *dllmain* commits the IAT patch, but I need an idea for **a windows application and an api function (like user32/kernel32 functions) which patching them will create a malicious behavior in the process which executes the app** (the most simple example is patching the MessageBox api from user32 in notepad, but I need something more "malicious".

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

You could patching some functions which using Windows registry keys like RegOpenKey from Advapi32 or in more basic some classic function like memccpy or malloc